# Cant get all response data from fetch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So I'm trying to store some info in the session, for later use. But when I fetch it in react, it doesn't all come back. Despite the get route having all of the data.

My thought process is on the serverside, when a user logs in store their id in the session. I'll then have a `/userinfo` route that dumps all the data i need in json. I can then fetch that `/userinfo` route and get the data in the response. My code is as follows:

Heres the post code to sign in, I `console.log` to verify the session is modified. It is.

```
User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
   if (error || !user) {
     var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
     err.status = 401;
     return next(err);
  } else {
     req.session.userId = user._id;
     console.log(req.session);
     return res.redirect('/');
   }
 });
```

Then I have this route:

```
app.get('/userinfo', (req, res)=>{
  res.json(req.session);
});
```

If I simply go to `localhost:3000/userinfo` the json looks like:

```
{
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge": null,
    "expires": null,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "path": "/"
  },
  "userId": "blahblahblah"
}
```

so UserID is indeed there.
However, when I finally go to fetch it in react with:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/userinfo')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

All I get back is the cookie. I dont get *UserId*. I've tried adding UserId to the cookie as well, just to see if it'd work, and likewise I just get the plain cookie.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Colin all I get is `{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue myself, I didn't even think about it, but I'm making the request from the client, so when I make the request through `fetch()` 
to 
`app.get('/userinfo', (req, res)=>{
  res.json(req.session);
});`

the server is returning the session stored on the clientside, which hasnt been updated with userId. So I need to return session data from the serverside, rather than from the client request.

My solution is to create and maintain a User object on the server-side and when I need to access user data, grab it from the user object.